# How to use a variable in the parameters of an element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use the following code to create a few `<div>` elements in a `v-for` loop:

```
<div class="row" v-for="sentinel in sentinels">
    <div class="cell date">{{ sentinel.when }}</div>
    <div class="cell city">{{ sentinel.city }}</div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly.

I now wanted to extend this with an `<img>` element:

```
<div class="row" v-for="sentinel in sentinels">
    <div class="cell date">{{ sentinel.when }}</div>
    <div class="cell city">{{ sentinel.city }}</div>
    <div class="cell country"><img src={{ sentinel.flagURL }} title={{ sentinel.country }}></div>
</div>
```

This fails with a `Uncaught Error: Error parsing template:(…)` error in the console.

`sentinel.flagURL` and `sentinel.country` has the correct (expected) value when checking with the debugger.

**Is it possible to use the variables (`{{ sentinel.whatever }}` for the case above) not only between opening and closing tags but also for the parameters of the tag?**

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: @epascarello: thank you. I edited your link into the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply bind your element [without mustaches](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Attributes):

```
<div class="cell country"><img :src="sentinel.flagURL" :title="sentinel.country"></div>
```

Image tag in HTML:

```
<img src="">
```